# ColdFusion & Ajax: Error Invoking CFC

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cfc, coldfusion-9

I have tried multiple tutorials on this topic from Forta.com and yet run into the same error:
*"Error invoking CFC/....(file path)../wgn.cfc: Internal Server Error [Enable 
debugging by adding 'cfdebug to your URL parameters to see more info]"*

I am working on my local machine and testing as localhost.  Running WinXP Pro with sp3.  Using Coldfusion's web server.

Both my .cfm and .cfc are in the same folder under the the webroot.  In my case:
*c:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\bridges(.cfm and .cfc here)*
So, they are in a "bridges" folder under wwwroot.

The code should generate some autosuggest functionality when the user types in the input box.  Instead, it just spits back the above error.

This is my cfc named wgn.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cfset THIS.dsn="bridges">
      <!--- Lookup used for auto suggest --->
      <cffunction name="getWGN" access="remote" returntype="array">
        <cfargument name="search" type="any" required="false" default="">
        <!--- Define variables --->
        <cfset var data="">
        <cfset var result=ArrayNew(1)>
        <!--- Do search --->
        <cfquery datasource="#THIS.dsn#" name="data">
        SELECT tblIDs.ID
        FROM tblIDs
        WHERE (tblIDs.IDType = 'xxx') AND (tblIDs.ID Like ('#ARGUMENTS.search#%'));
        </cfquery>
        <!--- Build result array --->
        <cfloop query="data">
        <cfset ArrayAppend(result, searchIDs)>
        </cfloop>
         <!--- And return it --->
        <cfreturn result>
       </cffunction>  
</cfcomponent>
```

And this is the relevant part of the form from my .cfm page:

```
    <cfform .....>
    <cfinput name="searchIDs" type="text" autosuggest="cfc:wgn.getWGN({cfautosuggestvalue})">
    //......more to form, obviously
    </cfform>
```

Comment: What do you get if you hit the cfc directly: http://www.domain.com/path/wgn.cfc?method=getWGN&search={someterm}

Comment: First thing to test is your CFC. Does it work when called independently with cfinvoke? [code]<cfinvoke component="wgn" method="getWGN" search="some value" returnVariable="result">
<cfdump var="#result#">[/code]  Second, IIRC robust debugging might interfere with ajax. Assuming you are working locally, try disabling it.

Comment: So the obvious question is - what does your logs say?

Comment: @Edward:  If I try http://localhost:8500/bridge/wgn.cfc?method=getWGN&search={1}   where "1" is what I would have started typing into the input box, nothing happens.  I get a completely blank page.

Comment: @Leigh, Didn't have robust debugging on in the first place.  Will try to figure out how to use the <cfinvoke> next...

Comment: @Jedi, I turned on the Enable AJAX Debug Log Window setting but wasn't sure how to use it.  I looked in the exception.log file and one of the last things I see is: "Error","web-173","10/13/10","11:43:44",,"Variable SEARCHIDS is undefined. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\CoveredBridgesSpatial\wgn.cfc, line: 22 "
coldfusion.runtime.UndefinedVariableException: Variable SEARCHIDS is undefined.     I changed the name of the input box to this to get rid of the underscore and also made that change in the cfc so they match.

Comment: @Leigh, tried your idea as: <cfinvoke component="wgn" method="getWGN" search="10" returnVariable="result"> <cfdump var="#result#">   where "10" would be what I would have entered in the input box.  Spits back the same error I see all over now:  Variable SEARCHIDS is undefined.

Comment: GOT IT.  Thanks.  Clearly, I was confused by the sample code I followed.  Removed "searchIDs" and put in "ID" (the field being returned) and it worked.  thanks

Comment: @stuttsdc - Yep. I just noticed that too. Good job.  BTW: Always test CFC's independently first. If they do not work by themselves, they definitely will not work when called via ajax ;)

Comment: @Leigh.  Will do.  That was a learning lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Solution:

```
change
 <cfset ArrayAppend(result, searchIDs)>
to
 <cfset ArrayAppend(result, ID)>
```